# Goldbach's conjecture

Tags: code-golf, primes

Write a program that prompts the user for an even integer greater than 2.

Given Goldbach’s conjecture that every even integer greater than 2 can 
be expressed as the sum of two primes, print out two prime numbers which, when 
added together, provide the requested even number.
Edit: the program only has to print A PAIR of primes, not all.
For example:

4 : 2 + 2

6: 3 + 3

8: 3 + 5

10: 5 + 5 or 3 + 7

Comment: *"only has to print a pair of primes"* Does that mean we are allowed to print more pairs?

Comment: I suppose if it shortens the length of your code, but it should be organized

Answer (score 11):

## APL, 34 or 44 bytes

The first version is **34** symbol long and is restricted to characters from the original single-byte APL charsets, such as the one still supported in Dyalog APL:

```
↑c/⍨n=+/¨c←,∘.,⍨v/⍨~v∊v∘.×v←1↓⍳n←⎕
```

Explanation:

```
                               n←⎕   ⍝ ask for a number, store as n
                          v←1↓⍳n     ⍝ generate all integers from 2 to n
                      v∘.×v          ⍝ compute the product table of any two such integers
                v/⍨~v∊               ⍝ select those that don't appear in the product table 
         c←,∘.,⍨                     ⍝ generate all possible pairs of these primes
    n=+/¨c                           ⍝ check which pairs have a sum equal to n
↑c/⍨                                 ⍝ take the first that does
```

---

The second version is only **22** symbol long, because it exploits the `π` function to check for prime numbers, but that's only available in [NARS2000](http://www.nars2000.org/) which uses Unicode, so the byte count is **44** in UCS-2:

```
2⍴(⌿⍨{∧/0π⍵})(⍪,⌽)⍳⎕-1
```

Explanation:

```
                   ⎕    ⍝ ask for a number N
                  ⍳ -1  ⍝ generate all naturals from 1 to N-1
             (⍪,⌽)      ⍝ arrange it into a table of all pairs of naturals with sum N
     {∧/0π⍵}            ⍝ check which pairs are made of all primes
2⍴(⌿⍨       )           ⍝ return the first pair that does
```

**Examples**

(⎕: is the prompt asking for a number)

```
      2⍴(⌿⍨{∧/0π⍵})(⍪,⌽)⍳⎕-1
⎕:
      4
2 2
      2⍴(⌿⍨{∧/0π⍵})(⍪,⌽)⍳⎕-1
⎕:
      6
3 3
      2⍴(⌿⍨{∧/0π⍵})(⍪,⌽)⍳⎕-1
⎕:
      8
3 5
      2⍴(⌿⍨{∧/0π⍵})(⍪,⌽)⍳⎕-1
⎕:
      124
11 113
```

Comment: Would `¯2π⍳2πn` work as a prime generator?

Comment: @Oberon what does the `π` operator do exactly?

Comment: Dyadic `π` switches with `⍺`: `¯2πx` calculates the xth prime, `¯1πx` is the first prime less than x, `0πx` tests x for primality, `1πx` is the first prime greater than x, `2πx` is the number of primes less than x, `10πx` is the number of divisors of x, `11πx` is the sum of all divisors of x, `12πx` and `13πx` are the Möbius and totient function, respectively. Last but not least, the monadic `πx` returns the prime factorization of x.

Comment: @Oberon that's specific to NARS2000, isn't it? Seems to be an interesting interpreter. I'll try it out and revise my answer.

Comment: @Tobia It is? Sorry then. I saw it referenced somewhere, but they never mentioned NARS2000. Good to know.

Comment: @Oberon that's a really nice addition. I should add that to my keyboard layout.

Comment: `2⍴(⌿⍨{∧/0π⍵})(⍪,⌽)⍳⎕-1` has 22 *characters*, but 41 *bytes* (UTF-8). According to the blurb on the code-golf tag, the scoring criterion is *byte*-count.

Comment: @r.e.s. @Tobia as soon the code became NARS2000 specific (using `π`), it would need to be in UCS-2 (i.e. exactly 2 bytes per character) as this is the [*only* available encoding](http://wiki.nars2000.org/index.php/Unicode) for NARS2000. Other APLs at least have an option of staying within 256 characters. Dyalog APL currently has three symbols that force non-256 char encoding; `⍠⍤⌸`, but as long as one doesn't use those, 1 byte/char is justified.

Comment: @Adám Agreed. Fixed.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, <s>75</s> 71 bytes

```python
n=input();k=m=1;p={0}
while{n-k,k}-p:m*=k*k;k+=1;p|={m%k*k}
print n-k,k
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/r6QiFE).

#### How it works

We use a corollary of [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem):

[image: corollary of Wilson's theorem]

At all times, the variable **m** is equal to the square of the factorial of **k - 1**; **k** starts at value **1** and **m** at value **0!² = 1**. The set **p** will consist of **0** and all prime numbers up to the current value of **k**.

In each iteration, we first check if both **n - k** and **k** belong to **p**, which is true if and only if the set difference of **{n-k, k}** and **p** is empty. If it is, the condition is falsy and the loop continues.

Note that **k > 0**, and **{n - k, k}** will satisfy the condition for some positive value of **n - k** (assuming that Goldbach's conjecture is true), so the **0** in **p** won't lead to false positives.

In the loop, we update **k** and **m**. The new value of **m** is **m × k² = (k - 1)!² × k² = k!²**, and the new value of **k** is **k + 1**, so **m = (k - 1)!²** still holds before and after the update.

Then, we perform set union to add the value of **m % k × k** to **p**. By the corollary of Wilson's theorem, this will add **1 × k = k** if **k** is prime and **0 × k = 0** if not.

When the loop ends, we print the last values of **n - k** and **k**, which will be primes with sum **n**.

Comment: How on earth does that prime generating algorithm work?

Comment: @LeakyNun I've added an explanation.

Comment: Oh... that is genius.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby 2.0 (65)

```
require'prime'
n=gets.to_i
Prime.find{|i|p [i,n-i]if(n-i).prime?}
```

Answer (score 4):

### PHP - 73 bytes

```
<?for(;@($n%--$$n?:$o=&$argv[1]>$$n=++$n)||${++$b}^${--$o};);echo"$b+$o";
```

Input is taken as a command line argument.

Sample usage:

```
$ php goldbach.php 7098
19+7079
```

Answer (score 4):

### GolfScript <del>41</del> <del>33</del>  32

```
~(,2>.-1%]zip{{.,2>\{\%!}+,},!}?
```

Accepts command line argument e.g.

```
echo "14" | ruby golfscript.rb goldbach.gs
-> [2 12]
```

Finds all relevant partitions of the input number with:

```
(,2>.-1%]zip  #If only zip were a one-character command!  It is so often useful.
```

and then finds the first partition where no numbers are NOT prime with:

```
{np,!}? #For each partition, filter down to elements that are not prime, and only accept if there are no such results (since [] is falsey).
```

where the composite-checking block `np` is:

```
{.,2>\{\%!}+,}
```

this block filters down to all numbers that evenly divide a given number.  If there are no such numbers (so the number is prime), the result is `[]`, which is falsey in GolfScript.

Answer (score 3):

#### R, <s>170</s> <s>112</s> 83 characters

```
a=scan();b=2:a;p=b[rowSums(!outer(b,b,`%%`))<2];q=p[(a-p)%in%p][1];cat(a,":",q,a-q)
```

Indented:

```r
a=scan() #Take user input as a numeric
b=2:a
p=b[rowSums(!outer(b,b,`%%`))<2] #Find all primes from 2 to user input
q=p[(a-p)%in%p][1] #Check which a-p also belong to p and takes the first one
cat(a,":",q,a-q)
```

Usage:

```
> a=scan();b=2:a;p=b[rowSums(!outer(b,b,`%%`))<2];q=p[(a-p)%in%p][1];cat(a,":",q,a-q)
1: 72
2: 
Read 1 item
72 : 5 67
```

**Old solution at 112 characters, for posterity**

```
a=scan();b=2:a;p=b[rowSums(!outer(b,b,`%%`))<2];w=which(outer(p,p,`+`)==a,T);cat(a,":",p[w[1,1]],p[w[1,2]])
```

Indented:

```r
a=scan()
b=2:a
p=b[rowSums(!outer(b,b,`%%`))<2]
w=which(outer(p,p,`+`)==a,T) #Find the index of valid combinations
cat(a,":",p[w[1,1]],p[w[1,2]]) #Prints the first valid combination
```

Comment: This is both crazy and genial!!

Answer (score 3):

### perl 6:  69

```
$/=get;for grep &is-prime,^$/ {exit say $_,$_-$/ if ($/-$_).is-prime}
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6) (Regex), 105

```
a=/^(xx+?)(?!(xx+)\2+$)x*(?=\1$)(?!(xx+)\3+$)/.exec("x".repeat(prompt()));alert(a[1].length+"+"+a[0].length)
```

Now you have a regex that tests the Goldbach conjecture, which has low requirement on special features (basic back-reference support, positive and negative look-ahead).

This uses [`String.prototype.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat), which is part of EcmaScript 6th edition proposal. Currently, this code only works on Firefox.

I really need a better language that has terse command when working with regex...

Answer (score 3):

## Python - 107

Basically an improvement on the second part of nutria's answer
(I ran this on 2.7 but I think it should also work for 3.x)

```
p=lambda x:all(x%i!=0 for i in range(2,x))
n=input()
for i in range(2,n-1):
    if p(i)&p(n-i): print i,n-i
```

Comment: Are the newlines, and spaces after `:` mandatory?

Comment: The tab could be reduced to a space, and the space before the print could be removed (shaves off 4 bytes).

Answer (score 2):

### Scala, <s>286</s> <s>192</s> <s>172</s> 148 chars

Not the fastest but it works. Call g(10) to obtain the list of goldbach pairs for 10.

```
def g(n:Int)={def p(n:Int,f:Int=2):Boolean=f>n/2||n%f!=0&&p(n,f+1)
s"$n : "+(for(i<-2 to n/2;j=n-i if p(i)&&p(j))yield s"$i + $j").mkString(" or ")}
```

Conversion to C++ is straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

#### newLISP - <strike>169</strike> 148 chars

```
(define(p n)(=(length(factor n))1))
(define(g n)(when(even? n)(for(i 3 n 2)
(and(p i)(p(- n i))(println n {: } i { }(- n i))))))
(g(int(read-line)))
```

includes the code to run it. The results are over-generous...

```
72: 5 67
72: 11 61
72: 13 59
72: 19 53
72: 29 43
72: 31 41
72: 41 31
72: 43 29
72: 53 19
72: 59 13
72: 61 11
72: 67 5
```

Answer (score 2):

## C - <strike>139</strike> 129 characters

```
a,b;i(x,y){return x>y?x%y?i(x,y+1):0:x>1;}main(){scanf("%i",&a);for(b=a/2;b-->1;)i(b,2)&&i(a-
b,2)&&printf("%i:%i+%i\n",a,b,a-b);}
```

Comment: You can shave 8 characters by removing the `int` declarations in your function `i`.  You can save another 2 characters by removing the `if` and adding in another double ampersand: `i(b,2)&&i(a-b,2)&&printf(...)`

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think of that `&&`. (I'll never get used to argument type silencing...)

Comment: I love your use of the nested ternary.

Answer (score 2):

### [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/), <s>65</s> 62

```
n=input()
i=0
p=is_prime
while p(i)*p(n-i)==0:i+=1
print i,n-i
```

With the above in file `goldbach.sage`, execute it with Sage running in a terminal:

```
sage: %runfile goldbach.sage
```

Thanks to @boothby for the `p=is_prime` idea.

Comment: You can get this down to 62 by setting `p=is_prime`.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica 56

This returns all of the solutions for the input integer.

```
Select[Tuples[Prime@Range@PrimePi[n = Input[]], 2], Tr@# == n &]
```

For example, when 1298 is input…

> {{7, 1291}, {19, 1279}, {61, 1237}, {67, 1231}, {97, 1201}, {127, 
>     1171}, {181, 1117}, {211, 1087}, {229, 1069}, {277, 1021}, {307, 
>     991}, {331, 967}, {379, 919}, {421, 877}, {439, 859}, {487, 
>     811}, {541, 757}, {547, 751}, {571, 727}, {607, 691}, {691, 
>     607}, {727, 571}, {751, 547}, {757, 541}, {811, 487}, {859, 
>     439}, {877, 421}, {919, 379}, {967, 331}, {991, 307}, {1021, 
>     277}, {1069, 229}, {1087, 211}, {1117, 181}, {1171, 127}, {1201, 
>     97}, {1231, 67}, {1237, 61}, {1279, 19}, {1291, 7}}

As written, it returns each solution twice.

```
Union[Sort/@ %]
```

> {{7, 1291}, {19, 1279}, {61, 1237}, {67, 1231}, {97, 1201}, {127, 
>     1171}, {181, 1117}, {211, 1087}, {229, 1069}, {277, 1021}, {307, 
>     991}, {331, 967}, {379, 919}, {421, 877}, {439, 859}, {487, 
>     811}, {541, 757}, {547, 751}, {571, 727}, {607, 691}}

Comment: Input 2, ask an oracle if it halts, prove/disprove the twin primes conjecture, win

Comment: [With this MSE solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132701/26598) we can do it in 47 bytes: `Cases[{1,1}~FrobeniusSolve~Input[],{__?PrimeQ}]` or even in 42 bytes as a function: `Cases[{1,1}~FrobeniusSolve~#,{__?PrimeQ}]&`.

Answer (score 2):

### Sage, 60

Similar in score and feel to [r.e.s.'s solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19512/2180), but I think it's different enough to post.

```
i=n=input()
while not{i,n-i}<set(primes(n)):i-=1
print i,n-i
```

Answer (score 2):

Haskell, 97C

```
g n=head[(a,b)|let q=p n,a<-q,b<-q,a+b==n]
p n=filter c[2..n]
c p=null[x|x<-[2..p-1],p`mod`x==0]
```

Explanation:

- `g` is the "goldbach" function. Calling `g n` gives you the pair of primes that add up to `n`.
- `p` is a function that generates a list of primes less than `n`.
- `c` is the prime checker function used to define `p`.

Example runs:

```
*Main> g 4
(2,2)
*Main> g 6
(3,3)
*Main> g 8
(3,5)
*Main> g 10
(3,7)
*Main> g 12
(5,7)
*Main> map g [4,6..100]
[(2,2),(3,3),(3,5),(3,7),(5,7),(3,11),(3,13),(5,13),(3,17),(3,19),(5,19),(3,23),(5,23),(7,23),(3,29),(3,31),(5,31),(7,31),(3,37),(5,37),(3,41),(3,43),(5,43),(3,47),(5,47),(7,47),(3,53),(5,53),(7,53),(3,59),(3,61),(5,61),(7,61),(3,67),(5,67),(3,71),(3,73),(5,73),(7,73),(3,79),(5,79),(3,83),(5,83),(7,83),(3,89),(5,89),(7,89),(19,79),(3,97)]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, <s>50</s> 49 bytes

```julia
~=primes;n=ARGS[]|>int
(n-~n)∩~n|>extrema|>show
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=fj1wcmltZXM7bj1BUkdTW118PmludAoobi1-biniiKl-bnw-ZXh0cmVtYXw-c2hvdw&input=&args=NTAw)

If a function were acceptable, the code could be shortened to **32 bytes**:

```julia
~=primes
!n=(n-~n)∩~n|>extrema
```

#### How it works

`~=primes` creates an alias for the built-in **primes** function which returns a list of all prime numbers up to its argument. `n=ARGS[]|>int` parses the first command-line argument as saves it in **n**.

To find a suitable pair of primes, we first compute the aforementioned prime range with `~n`. Then, `n-~n` yields all differences of these primes and **n**.

By intersecting (`∩`) the result with the prime range itself, we make sure that the remaining primes **p** are such that **n - p** is also a prime.

Finally, `extrema` takes the lowest and highest prime in the intersection, so their sum must be **n**.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3 - <del>150</del> 143 characters

Old version (150 characters):

```
p=lambda n:0 in[n % i for i in range(2,n)]
n=int(input())
[print('%d+%d'%(a, b))for b in range(2,n)for a in range(2,n)if not(a+b!=n or p(a) or p(b))]
```

New version (thanks to ProgramFOX):

```
p=lambda n:0 in[n%i for i in range(2,n)]
n=int(input())
[print('%d+%d'%(a,b))for b in range(2,n)for a in range(2,n)if not((a+b!=n)|p(a)|p(b))]
```

It prints every combination, for example:

4
2+2
10 7+3 5+5 3+7

Comment: `|` can safely be used with boolean type, so `(a+b!=n)|p(a)|p(b)`

Comment: Even shorter by using: `print([(a,b)for b in range(2,n)for a in range(2,n)if not((a+b!=n)|p(a)|p(b))])` (prints a list of tuples, whose sum is n). Saves 8 bytes.

Comment: Also using `r=range(2,n)` and referencing `r` saves a few more.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <del>139</del> <del>137</del> 136

```
a=prompt();function b(n){for(i=2;i<n;i++)if(n%i<1)return;return 1}for(c=2,r=1;c<a&&r;c++)if(b(c)&&b(a-c))alert(a+": "+c+" + "+(a-c)),r=0
```

Comment: I think you can shave off 2 more chars by `return;` instead of `return 0;`

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 62 Chars (85 with prompt)

```
julia> g(n)=collect(filter((x)->sum(x)==n,combinations(primes(n),2)))
g (generic function with 1 method)

julia> g(88)
4-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [5,83] 
 [17,71]
 [29,59]
 [41,47]
```

Comment: This doesn't prompt the user (as required), does it?

Comment: No, didn't notice that.  It would add many characters right now julia.  `g(int(readline(STDIN)))`

Answer (score 1):

### [GTB](http://timtechsoftware.com/gtb), 31

*For your TI-84 Calculator*

```
`A:.5A→B@%;A,4)4$~B+1,B-1#~B,B&
```

No prime built-ins.

**Example runs**

```
?4
               2
               2
?6
               3
               3
?8
               3
               5
?10
               5
               5
```

Answer (score 1):

## q [116 chars]

```
y where all each{{2=count where 0=(x mod)each til x+1}each x}each y:{a where x=sum each a:a cross a:til x}"I"$read0 0
```

No inbuilt function to find prime number.

Input

```
72
```

Output

```
5  67
11 61
13 59
19 53
29 43
31 41
41 31
43 29
53 19
59 13
61 11
67 5
```

Answer (score 1):

## J - <s>35</s> 32 char

"Prompt the user" is the bane of every J golfer. There go all my hard-earned characters!

```
p:(n,n)#:i.&n,+/~p:i.n=:".1!:1]1
```

Explained:

- `".1!:1]1` - Read in a string (`1!:1`) from input (file handle `1`) and convert it to a number (`".`).
- `p:i.n=:` - Assign this number to the variable `n`, and then take the first `n` primes.
- `+/~` - Make an addition table, `n` wide and `n` high.
- `i.&n,` - Turn the table into a single list, and then find the index of the first occurrence of `n`, which exists if Goldbach's conjecture is true.
- `p:(n,n)#:` - Retrieve the row and column from the index, and take the corresponding primes.

Usage:

```
   p:(n,n)#:i.&n,+/~p:i.n=:".1!:1]1
666
5 661
   p:(n,n)#:i.&n,+/~p:i.n=:".1!:1]1
1024
3 1021
```

Had the prompt not been a requirement, here's a 25 character verb:

```
(,~p:@#:]i.~&,+/~@:p:@i.)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python - 206

A little late to the party but I am practicing my golfing skills.

I actually coded this before I found this question! So mine doesn't include the beautiful lambda that the other Python solutions use.

```
import math
def p(n):
    if n%2==0&n>2:return False
    for i in range(3,n):
        if n%i==0:return False
    return True 
X=int(input())
for i in range(2,X):
    if p(i)&p(X-i):print i,X-i;break
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) (non-competing)

```
_ÆRfÆR.ị
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=X8OGUmbDhlIu4buL&input=&args=NTAw) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=X8OGUmbDhlIu4buLCsOH4oKsRw&input=&args=NCwgNiwgOCwgMTA).

#### How it works

```
_ÆRfÆR.ị  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

 ÆR       Prime range; yield all primes in [1, ..., n].
_         Subtract all primes from n.
   fÆR    Filter; intersect the list of differences with the prime range.
      .ị  At-index 0.5; yield the last and first element.
```

Answer (score 1):

Python3 version of [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19881/110481) -110 bytes

```python
p=lambda x:all(x%i!=0 for i in range(2,x))
n=int(input())
for i in range(2,n-1):
 if p(i)&p(n-i): print(i,n-i)
```

and a super golfed version:

```python
exec(bytes('㵰慬扭慤砠愺汬砨椥㴡‰潦⁲⁩湩爠湡敧㈨砬⤩渊椽瑮椨灮瑵⤨਩潦⁲⁩湩爠湡敧㈨測ㄭ㨩 晩瀠椨☩⡰⵮⥩›牰湩⡴Ⱪ⵮⥩','u16')[2:])
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Comment: This program does not run and it is unclear what your actual code is. Also, neither of the two programs you wrote match the bytecount you specified. Please fix your answer and properly format the code.

Comment: @Makonede i fixed the issues you found.

Comment: [Your code still doesn't work,](https://i.imgur.com/OL5BfUv.png) and the bytecount is still wrong. Also, like I asked, please properly format your code.

Comment: @Makonede sorry i've been testing this on my computers Python interpreter and getting the byte count from a file i store the code in on my computer.

Comment: `p` is still not defined. you need to add the definition of `p` to this program.

Comment: @Razetime thanks for noticing when i was making the answer it didn't show the first line.

Comment: ok, now that it is working, you should remove the input prompt since this is code golf. Your other supergolfed version is 199 bytes.

Comment: Both of these now take input from a predefined variable (`n`), which is not an allowed input method. What Razetime was suggestion was to delete the useless phrase "Enter an even number: ", not to delete the entire line and turn the code into a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch - 266

```
@echo off&setLocal enableDelayedExpansion&for /L %%a in (2,1,%1)do (set/aa=%%a-1&set c=&for /L %%b in (2,1,!a!)do set/ab=%%a%%%%b&if !b!==0 set c=1
if !c! NEQ 1 set l=!l!%%a,)&for %%c in (!l!)do for %%d in (!l!)do set/ad=%%c+%%d&if !d!==%1 set o=%%c + %%d
echo !o!
```

Set out neatly -

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%a in (2,1,%1) do (
    set /a a=%%a-1
    set c=
    for /L %%b in (2,1,!a!) do (
        set /a b=%%a%%%%b
        if !b!==0 set c=1
    )
    if !c! NEQ 1 set l=!l!%%a,
)
for %%c in (!l!) do for %%d in (!l!) do (
    set /a d=%%c+%%d
    if !d!==%1 set o=%%c + %%d
)
echo !o!
```

Answer (score 0):

## SQL, <del>295</del> 284

In postgresql:

```
create function c(c int) returns table (n int, m int) as $$ 
with recursive i(n) as
(select 2 union all select n+1 from i where n<c), 
p as (select * from i a where not exists 
(select * from i b where a.n!=b.n and mod(a.n,b.n)=0))
select * from p a, p b where a.n+b.n=c 
$$ language sql;
```

Should be able to do it in half the space though, if it weren't for things like "no left outer join in recursion", "no subquery in recursion"...

Here's the output:

```
postgres=# select c(10);
   c   
-------
 (3,7)
 (5,5)
 (7,3)
(3 rows)

postgres=# select c(88);
   c    
---------
 (5,83)
 (17,71)
 (29,59)
 (41,47)
 (47,41)
 (59,29)
 (71,17)
 (83,5)
(8 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl 5, 58 bytes

57, plus 1 for `-nE`

```
/^(11+?)(?!(11+)\2+$)1*(?=\1$)(?!(11+)\3+$)/;say for$1,$&
```

Input and output are in unary. Example:

```
$ perl -nE'/^(11+?)(?!(11+)\2+$)1*(?=\1$)(?!(11+)\3+$)/;say for$1,$&'
1111111111
111
1111111
```

[Hat-tip.](/a/19528)

Answer (score 0):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 202 bytes

```sql
WITH v(x,y,s)AS(SELECT LEVEL,LEVEL,0 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<=:1 UNION ALL SELECT x,y-1,s+SIGN(MOD(x,y))FROM v WHERE y>1),p AS(SELECT x FROM v WHERE x-s=2)SELECT a.x,b.x FROM p a,p b WHERE:1=a.x+b.x;
```

Un-golfed

```sql
WITH v(x,y,s) AS
(
  SELECT LEVEL,LEVEL,0 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<=:1 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT x,y-1,s+SIGN(MOD(x,y))FROM v WHERE y>1
)
,p AS (SELECT x FROM v WHERE x-s=2)
SELECT a.x,b.x 
FROM p a,p b 
WHERE :1=a.x+b.x;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3, 107 bytes

```
b=lambda x:all(x%y for y in range(2,x))
g=lambda x,i=2:((i,x-i)if b(i)&b(x-i)else g(x,i+1))if(i<x)else 0
```

b(x) is a primality test for x, and g(x) recurses through numbers to find two primes that fit.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
ÅP©-ʒ®så}Á2£
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9vc2FiaWX//8OFUMKpLcqSwq5zw6V9w4EywqP//zEw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
œP2ṚæS:
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNSU5M1AyJUUxJUI5JTlBJUMzJUE2UyUzQSZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTQlMjAlMjAlMjMlM0ElMjAyJTIwJTJCJTIwMiUwQTYlMjAlMjAlMjMlM0ElMjAzJTIwJTJCJTIwMyUwQTglMjAlMjAlMjMlM0ElMjAzJTIwJTJCJTIwNSUwQTEwJTIwJTIzJTNBJTIwNSUyMCUyQiUyMDUlMjBvciUyMDMlMjAlMkIlMjA3JmZsYWdzPVY=)

Prints all possible pairs. If you only want one, add the `h` flag.

##### Explanation

```python
œP2ṚæS:  # Implicit input
œP       # Filter [1..input] for primes
   Ṛ     # Combinations with replacement
  2      # with a length of two
    æS:  # Filter by sum equals input
         # Implicit output
```