# Backhanded^H^H^H^H^H^Hspaces

Tags: code-golf, string

On some terminals, pressing backspace generates the control code `^H` to delete the previous character. This gave rise to a snarky idiom where [edits are feigned for comedic effect](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/writing-style.html):

> Be nice to this fool^H^H^H^Hgentleman, he's visiting from corporate
>   HQ.

Given a string with one or more `^H`'s, output the result of backspacing on each `^H`. The input will use only printable characters (ASCII 32-126), and `^` will only appear as `^H`. Backspaces will never happen on empty text.

You may not assume that the output environment supports control codes, in particular the backspace code `\x08`.

```
>> Horse^H^H^H^H^HCow
Cow

>> Be nice to this fool^H^H^H^Hgentleman, he's visiting from corporate HQ.
Be nice to this gentleman, he's visiting from corporate HQ.

>> 123^H45^H^H^H78^H
17

>> Digital Trauma^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^HMaria Tidal Tug^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^HDigital Trauma
Digital Trauma
```

### Leaderboard

Here's a by-language leaderboard, courtesy of [Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner).

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

```js
function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/52946/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function getAnswers(){$.ajax({url:answersUrl(page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:true,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items);if(e.has_more)getAnswers();else process()}})}function shouldHaveHeading(e){var t=false;var n=e.body_markdown.split("\n");try{t|=/^#/.test(e.body_markdown);t|=["-","="].indexOf(n[1][0])>-1;t&=LANGUAGE_REG.test(e.body_markdown)}catch(r){}return t}function shouldHaveScore(e){var t=false;try{t|=SIZE_REG.test(e.body_markdown.split("\n")[0])}catch(n){}return t}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){answers=answers.filter(shouldHaveScore).filter(shouldHaveHeading);answers.sort(function(e,t){var n=+(e.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG)||[Infinity])[0],r=+(t.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG)||[Infinity])[0];return n-r});var e={};var t=1;answers.forEach(function(n){var r=n.body_markdown.split("\n")[0];var i=$("#answer-template").html();var s=r.match(NUMBER_REG)[0];var o=(r.match(SIZE_REG)||[0])[0];var u=r.match(LANGUAGE_REG)[1];var a=getAuthorName(n);i=i.replace("{{PLACE}}",t++ +".").replace("{{NAME}}",a).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",u).replace("{{SIZE}}",o).replace("{{LINK}}",n.share_link);i=$(i);$("#answers").append(i);e[u]=e[u]||{lang:u,user:a,size:o,link:n.share_link}});var n=[];for(var r in e)if(e.hasOwnProperty(r))n.push(e[r]);n.sort(function(e,t){if(e.lang>t.lang)return 1;if(e.lang<t.lang)return-1;return 0});for(var i=0;i<n.length;++i){var s=$("#language-template").html();var r=n[i];s=s.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",r.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",r.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",r.size).replace("{{LINK}}",r.link);s=$(s);$("#languages").append(s)}}var QUESTION_ID=45497;var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";var answers=[],page=1;getAnswers();var SIZE_REG=/\d+(?=[^\d&]*(?:&lt;(?:s&gt;[^&]*&lt;\/s&gt;|[^&]+&gt;)[^\d&]*)*$)/;var NUMBER_REG=/\d+/;var LANGUAGE_REG=/^#*\s*((?:[^,\s]|\s+[^-,\s])*)/
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js></script><link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"><div id=answer-list><h2>Leaderboard</h2><table class=answer-list><thead><tr><td></td><td>Author<td>Language<td>Size<tbody id=answers></table></div><div id=language-list><h2>Winners by Language</h2><table class=language-list><thead><tr><td>Language<td>User<td>Score<tbody id=languages></table></div><table style=display:none><tbody id=answer-template><tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}<td>{{LANGUAGE}}<td>{{SIZE}}<td><a href={{LINK}}>Link</a></table><table style=display:none><tbody id=language-template><tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}<td>{{NAME}}<td>{{SIZE}}<td><a href={{LINK}}>Link</a></table>
```

Comment: Is `AAA^HB^H^H` valid?

Comment: @NathanMerrill Yes, and it results in `A`.

Comment: I suspect [retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina/) would do well here.

Comment: is `^HA`valid? More generally, can strings start with a useless backspace?

Comment: @Fatalize: "Backspaces will never happen on empty text."

Comment: [@Maria Tidal Tug](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=20883776#20883776) comes back to haunt me

Comment: The URL in the leaderboard snippet should be `https://`, since the snippet doesn't work in newer versions of Chrome that don't load insecure resources on pages loaded over HTTPS.

Comment: @Frxstrem Changed it to https.

Comment: I tried to implement this in the correct language for such a problem, `chicken`, but I'm new to chicken and gave up eventually...  I'd love to see if any senior chicken developers could post a solution.

Comment: @Frxstrem Or `//`

Comment: May we take input with actual backspaces?

Comment: @Adám No, use `^H`'s.

Comment: Suggested test case from ~3 years into the future: `H^Hello H^HLarry!`

Answer (score 69):

## GNU sed, 11 bytes

```
:;s/.^H//;t
```

#### Test output:

```
$ echo "Horse^H^H^H^H^HCow
Be nice to this fool^H^H^H^Hgentleman, he's visiting from corporate HQ.
123^H45^H^H^H78^H
Digital Trauma^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^HMaria Tidal Tug^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^HDigital Trauma" | sed ':;s/.^H//;t'
Cow
Be nice to this gentleman, he's visiting from corporate HQ.
17
Digital Trauma
$
```

Comment: Look who showed up! It's Maria Tidal Tug^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^HDigital Trauma!

Comment: @AlexA. Am I missing an in-joke?

Comment: @immibis: See [Digital Trauma's comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52946/backhandedhhhhhhspaces/52955?noredirect=1#comment126406_52946) on the question.

Comment: `sed -r ':;s/(^|.)\^H//;t'` - this works at expense of extra 6 bytes

Comment: @aragaer Why is that necessary? The OP says "*Backspaces will never happen on empty text*".  I think a `^H` the beginning of the string is a backspace on empty text.

Comment: I thought it was valid to press backspace more times than there are characters in front of it.... I do it all the time myself!

Answer (score 19):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
.U+PbZcz"^H
```

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.U%2BPbZcz%22%5EH&input=123%5EH45%5EH%5EH%5EH78%5EH&debug=0)

```
.U+PbZcz"^H
               Implicit: z = input()
      cz"^H    z.split("^H")
.U             reduce, with the first element of the list as the initial value.
   Pb          Remove the last character of what we have so far.
  +  Z         And add on the next segment.
               Print implicitly.
```

Answer (score 17):

## Gema, 6 bytes

```
?#\^H=
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema -p '?#\^H=' <<< 'pizza is alright^H^H^H^H^H^Hwesome'
pizza is awesome
```

CW, because the fool vs. gentleman example takes far too long. (Killed after a day. Maybe a glitch in the interpreter? All other examples here are processed in fractions of seconds.) Gema's recursive pattern not seems to be affected by the recursion level, but the amount of non-matching text increases processing time exponentially.

Comment: Is there a link to the language? A quick search on Github turned up quite a few

Comment: Sure. http://gema.sourceforge.net/ (BTW, the Gema project was registered 2003-10-27, while GitHub was launched 2008-04-10. That may be a reason to not find it there.)

Comment: I believe the recursion depth is equally to the length of the non-matching string, because it will recurse again and again until the `\^H` maches, matching one character at a time to the `?`.

Answer (score 15):

## C, 52 bytes

```c
j;f(char*s){for(j=0;*s=s[j];s[j]==94?s--,j+=3:s++);}
```

We define a function `f` that takes a pointer to the string as input. After the function call, that pointer will contain a modified string.

A simple test:

```c
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char buf[300] = "Digital Trauma^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^HMaria Tidal Tug^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^HDigital Trauma";
    f(buf);
    printf(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

The above prints:

```
Digital Trauma
```

Comment: This was really clever. A couple things I noticed: globals are already initialized to zero, so no need to init `j` in your `for` loop (of course then it's single use, but I don't see anything about that in the rules :) ). You can also combine the assignment with the decrement: `j;f(char*s){for(;s[j]==94?*s--=s[j],j+=3:s++);}` (47 bytes)

Comment: @ColeCameron [you missed this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4940/14509)

Comment: @undergroundmonorail dang, I was just double checking to see if I missed that. I'm still new to code golf but I'll remember that for the future :). Thanks for the info!

Comment: @ColeCameron No problem, it's easy to miss stuff (and it's good that you checked at all :P)

Comment: @ColeCameron That has an unsequenced modification and access (UB), and causes an immediate EXC_BAD_ACCESS on my compiler/machine, unfortunately.

Comment: You can replace `==` with `^` if you swap the last operands of `?:` :)

Comment: @Quentin I tried that, but because of the comma in `s--, j+=3` and operator precedence, it doesn't work right.

Comment: @BrainSteel oh, right.

Answer (score 14):

## Haskell, 47 bytes

```
h(a,_:_:b)=f$init a++b;h(x,_)=x
f=h.span(/='^')
```

Defines a function `f :: String -> String`. How it works:

```
    f "ab^Hc^Hd"
=== h ("ab", "^Hc^Hd")   (find ^H)
=== f ("a" ++ "c^Hd")    (backspace)
=== f "ac^Hd"            (join)
=== h ("ac", "^Hd")      (find ^H)
=== f ("a", "d")         (backspace)
=== f "ad"               (join)
=== h ("ad", "")         (find ^H)
=== "ad"                 (no ^H: base case)
```

Comment: I think you can save a byte by swapping the two cases of `h` and doing `h(x,_)=x` for the empty string case.

Answer (score 12):

## CJam, <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
q"^H"/{W\ts}*
```

**How it works**

```
q                   e# Read the entire input
 "^H"/              e# Split it on occurrences of string "^H"
      {    }*       e# Reduce on the split array
       W\t          e# This is the tricky part. We know that if there are two parts that we
                    e# are reducing on, they must be separated by "^H". Which in turn means
                    e# that from the first part, last characters needs to be deleted
                    e# So we simply put the second part in place of the last character of the
                    e# first part.
          s         e# Doing the above makes it a mixed array of character and string.
                    e# So we convert it to a single string, ready to be served as first part
                    e# in next reduce iteration
```

*UPDATE: 1 byte saved thanks to jimmy23013*

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%22%5EH%22%2F%7BW%5Cts%7D*&input=Digital%20Trauma%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EHMaria%20Tidal%20Tug%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EHDigital%20Trauma)

Comment: 1 byte shorter: ``W\ts``.

Answer (score 11):

## Retina, 13 bytes

[Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina)

```
+`.\^H(.*)
$1
```

The two lines should go to their own files but you can run the code as one file with the `-s` flag.

At each step we delete the first match for `.\^H` in the string. We repeat this (with the `+` modifier) until no deletion happens.

Comment: Just a curiosity: why the capturing of `(.*)`, as it seems to be just put back unchanged?

Comment: @manatwork This way we only capture the first `.\^H` in one step. Otherwise `abc^H^H^H` would result in `ab^` after the first step.

Comment: Apologies for not implementing a replacement limit yet (which would probably allow something like `+1\`.\^H`). ;)

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (*ES6*), 39 bytes

```js
f=s=>(t=s.replace(/.\^H/,''))!=s?f(t):t

// TEST

Out=x=>O.innerHTML+=x+'\n'

Test=_=>(Out(I.value + "\n-> " + f(I.value)),I.value='')

;["Horse^H^H^H^H^HCow"
,"Be nice to this fool^H^H^H^Hgentleman, he's visiting from corporate HQ."
,"123^H45^H^H^H78^H"
,"Digital Trauma^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^HMaria Tidal Tug^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^HDigital Trauma"]
.forEach(t => Out(t + "\n-> " + f(t)))
```

```css
#I { width:400px }
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
<input id=I><button onclick='Test()'>-></button>
```

Answer (score 10):

## Perl, <s>20</s> <s>16</s> 15 bytes

(14 characters code + 1 character command line option.)

```perl
s/.\^H//&&redo
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ perl -pe 's/.\^H//&&redo' <<< "Be nice to this fool^H^H^H^Hgentleman, he's visiting from corporate HQ."
Be nice to this gentleman, he's visiting from corporate HQ.
```

Comment: Save 4 characters: `1while s/.\^H//`

Comment: Wow! That's great @KevinReid. Thank you.

Comment: One more: `s/.\^H//&&redo`

Comment: Thank you, @Dennis. `redo` somehow not made its way into my skill set. Will have to change that.

Comment: Note that @Dennis's version will only work (as intended) if it's the only statement inside a loop or a `{ }` block. (The reason why it works with `perl -p` is that the `-p` switch automatically wraps your code inside a `while` loop.) Kevin's version works in any setting.

Answer (score 9):

## Julia, <s>58</s> <s>42</s> 41 bytes

Saved 16 bytes thanks to manatwork and 1 thanks to Glen O!

```matlab
f(s)='^'∈s?f(replace(s,r".\^H","",1)):s
```

This creates a recursive function that accepts a string and returns a string.

This replaces one occurrence of `^H` at a time with an empty string while the input contains `^`.

Examples:

```matlab
julia> f("123^H45^H^H^H78^H")
"17"

julia> f("pizza is alright^H^H^H^H^H^Hwesome")
"pizza is awesome"
```

Comment: This is the first time I've seen Julia in the wild. Nice!

Answer (score 8):

## REGXY, 10 bytes

Uses [REGXY](http://esolangs.org/wiki/REGXY), a regex substitution based language. Replaces any character followed by ^H with nothing. The second line then executes which is just a pointer to the previous line, repeating the substitution until it fails to match.

```
/.\^H//
//
```

This compiles and executes correctly with the sample interpreter in the link above, but the solution is perhaps a bit cheeky as it relies on an assumption in the vagueness of the language specification. The spec states that the first token on each line (before the /) acts as a label, but the assumption is that a null label-pointer will point back to the first command in the file with a null label (or in other words, that 'null' is a valid label). A less cheeky solution would be:

```
a/.\^H//
b//a
```

Which amounts to 13 bytes.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3, 53 bytes

```py
o=""
for x in input().split("^H"):o=o[:-1]+x
print(o)
```

But personally I like this wordier version better:

```py
H=input().split("^H")
print(eval("("*~-len(H)+")[:-1]+".join(map(repr,H))))
```

The interesting thing is that

```py
'B''a''c''k''h''a''n''d''e''d'[:-1][:-1][:-1][:-1][:-1][:-1]
```

actually works and gives `'Back'`, so I tried to map `^H  ->  [:-1]` and any other char `c  ->  'c'` then `eval`, but unfortunately you can't have any strings afterwards without a `+`, so this fails:

```py
'B''a''c''k''h''a''n''d''e''d'[:-1][:-1][:-1][:-1][:-1][:-1]'s''p''a''c''e''s'
```

Comment: Heyy... that's pretty neat.

Comment: `+=`works in the loop

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy It's `o=o[:-1]+x`, not `o=o+x`

Comment: Oops, missed that. Does something like `o[:-2]=x` work?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy You can't assign to `str`

Answer (score 7):

## Haskell, <s>52</s> 47 bytes

```
import Data.Lists
foldl1((++).init).splitOn"^H"
```

Usage example:

```
> map (foldl1((++).init).splitOn"^H") ["Horse^H^H^H^H^HCow", "123^H45^H^H^H78^H", "Digital Trauma^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^HMaria Tidal Tug^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^HDigital Trauma"]
["Cow","17","Digital Trauma"]
```

How it works:

```
                  splitOn"^H"     -- split on substring "^H", e.g "Horse^H^H^H^H^HCow" -> ["Horse","","","","","Cow"]
                 .                -- then
foldl1(         )                 -- fold from left by
            init                  --   first dropping the last char from the left argument
       (++).                      --   second concatenating left and right argument
```

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby, <s>27</s> <s>24</s> 20 bytes

(19 characters code + 1 character command line option.)

```ruby
$_=$`+$'while/.\^H/
```

Thanks to:

- [Ventero](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84/ventero) for suggesting to use the global variables (-4 characters)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ ruby -pe '$_=$`+$'"'"'while/.\^H/' <<< "Be nice to this fool^H^H^H^Hgentleman, he's visiting from corporate HQ."
Be nice to this gentleman, he's visiting from corporate HQ.
```

Comment: +1 I thought I'd do a Ruby answer until I saw this -- I'm pretty sure this is as small as it's gonna get. Great usage of `[]`!

Comment: There was another version in the beginning: `loop{$_[/.\^H/]=""}rescue""` This one is nicer as it demonstrates Ruby's exception handling coolness.

Comment: Haha, that's a great one :)

Comment: Better late than never: ``$_=$`+$'while~/.\^H/`` for 20 (you can even drop the tilde if you don't care about the `regexp literal in condition` warning).

Comment: Thank you, @Ventero. The warning appears only in `irb` (at least in 2.1.5), so I don't care about it, as I run the code from command line. :)

Comment: @manatwork: Technically it appears in all ruby versions >= 1.9 (regex and string literals in conditions were deprecated after 1.8), I guess your `ruby` simply still defaults 1.8, whereas `irb` uses ruby 2.1.5.

Comment: Thank you for the information on the deprecation, @Ventero. Sorry, for the confusing wording, that version 2.1.5 actually applies to both `ruby` and `irb`: http://pastebin.com/eZaWtirp My first guess was different verbose mode, but both are on medium.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org/), 12 bytes

```
qqt^3xh@qq@q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcIxCoAwDAXQq/zNRVy8QHHq6gUKItEG2sa0oXj7Osh7fQxVC@sbnarTMTZC4ZNgAovccImk4H83FUuUjzIj0tTQubFxuXFVyTilPlIPI/h9@QA)

Makes use of the fact that "`^` will only appear as `^H`".

#### Explanation

```
qqt^3xh@qq@q
qq     @qq@q    Define an indefinitely looping recursive macro and immediately call it
  t^            Move to just before the next ^ character in the line
    3x          Delete 3 characters (the one to be deleted, ^, and H)
      h         Move left 1 step (to be in position for the next search)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <sup><s>16</s></sup> 14 bytes

```
qq:s/.^H
@qq@q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcIxCoAwDAXQ3VP8zUV0dypOXb2AUCRqQBvThl4/DvJec1ed6zRusQuqQd0XQuadYAK7uOIQubf4OynbTU/KAy7qKxpXNs4njiIPdimvlGSEuI4f)

similar to sed, but uses Vim's recursion.

Comment: Nice! Looks like my regex would’ve been a lot simpler without the g flag

Comment: @OriginalOriginalOriginalVI replacing the first occurrence is simpler, but Leo's solution is just a ton smarter. I didn't notice that there were two other answers on this until I saw the thread :P

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth - 19 bytes

Reduce works really, really well with this but it only does one char at a time so I had to spend almost as many chars as the actual algo to do a replace `^H` with linebreak. Looking for a better way to do that.

```
u?+GHnHbPGjbcz"^H"k
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%3F%2BGHnHbPGjbcz%22%5EH%22k&input=Be%20nice%20to%20this%20fool%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EHgentleman%2C%20he%27s%20visiting%20from%20corporate%20HQ.&debug=1).

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 50

It's a bit odd having a second `lambda` in there, but seems to be the best Python so far.

```
lambda s:reduce(lambda a,b:a[:-1]+b,s.split('^H'))
```

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```
s->foldl((t,v)->chop(t)v,split(s,"^H"))
```

What it's doing is using ^H as a delimiter, and then removing the last character on each string then concatenating the next string before removing the last character again. Unlike the other Julia answer, this is not a recursive function.

Note: I've removed the function name from the definition. Originally, it said `f(s)=` rather than `s->`, and you used it as `f("AAA^HB^H^H")`... but I'm saving two bytes by letting it be "anonymous", and use itself as its name. You use it like this:

```
(s->foldl((t,v)->chop(t)v,split(s,"^H")))("AAA^HB^H^H")
```

(you can also assign a variable to it as `f=s->foldl((t,v)->chop(t)v,split(s,"^H"))`, then `f("AAA^HB^H^H")` will work)

Answer (score 3):

## [TeaScript](http://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript), 7 bytes [Not competing]

**Not competing** as TeaScript was made after this challenge was posted. This is here as reference.

```
xW/.\^H
```

This uses the new TeaScript 3, and recursive replaces to remove the characters

Comment: For some reason this counts as 8859 bytes on the leaderboard because of the ISO 8859 link...

Comment: `regerence`?  xD

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), 8 bytes

```
Ue/.\^H/
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VWUvLlxeSC8=&input=IjEyM15INDVeSF5IXkg3OF5IIg==)

#### How it works

```
U        // Take the input,
e/.\^H/  // and recursively replace any char followed by "^H" with
         // (nothing, defaults to an empty string).
         // Implicit: output last expression
```

Comment: As a small update many years later, the working solution now seems to be `e".\\^H`. I couldn't get the regex version to work with the current interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 81 bytes

```
>,[[>+>+<<-]-[>-<---]>---------[>>+<<[-]]>>-[+<[-]<<<,[-]>>]<[<<+>>-]<,]<[<]>[.>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fUyrDsMwEPuV8uT2BZbRQElZ2ekqXTe1Ou0BouX7swYMDGw2sGVbXovHc6uXW2vMqkxMgJgoBSJilA@UvVIxI0VTdwDyIaRBgXTkhty9UU@01s6xx8vvw1y8PnwZf3PyEj7Mce3ruv@bLuP37Rs)

Answer (score 2):

## ECMAScript 6, 57 bytes

```
s=>{while(~s.indexOf`^H`)s=s.replace(/.\^H/,'');return s}
```

This is <s>probably golfable, just gotta think of a way</s> probably not

Comment: How about `s=>{while(s!=(s=s.replace(/.\^H/,""));return s}`?

Comment: Or, if `while` and `return` are too long, it could be recursive: `var f=s=>s==(s=s.replace(/.\^H/))?s:f(s)`

Comment: @lm you should add the second parameter "" for replace. Then you have my answer :)

Comment: True. And the empty string argument needs to be there, I must have copied the wrong version :(

Comment: `~s.indexOf\`^H\`` can become `/\^H/.test(s)`

Comment: Generally `for` doesn't increase bytes over`while`

Comment: Try using eval: s=>eval("while(~s.indexOf\`^H`)s=s.replace(/.\^H/,'');s"). Untested, but it might work.

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```r
f=function(s)ifelse(s==(r=sub(".\\^H","",s)),r,f(r))
```

Same basic idea as [my Julia answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52959/20469). This creates a recursive function that accepts a string and returns a string. If the input is equal to itself with a single occurrence of `^H` removed, return it, otherwise call the function again.

You can [try it online](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=FJNnw6Xp)!

Answer (score 2):

## K5, 64 bytes

K isn't really designed for this kind of work...

```
{[s]$[2>#s;s;`=t:*&{"^H"~2#x_s}'1+!-2+#s;s;,/2#2!|(0,t,3+t)_s]}/
```

Answer (score 2):

## golflua, 36 bytes

```
\f(s)@o!=s o=s;s=s:g(".^H","",1)$~s$
```

Sample run:

```
Lua 5.2.2  Copyright (C) 1994-2013 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> \f(s)@o!=s o=s;s=s:g(".^H","",1)$~s$
> w(f("Be nice to this fool^H^H^H^Hgentleman, he's visiting from corporate HQ."))
Be nice to this gentleman, he's visiting from corporate HQ.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 62 bytes

Not the shortest one, but works fine.

```js
t=prompt();while(t.match(R=/.\^H/))t=t.replace(R,'');alert(t);
```

This probably can be shortened a lot!

Comment: Not the shortest one and does not work eiither (try any of the test cases). The regexp should not be global (remove /g)

Comment: @edc65 Thanks for the tip. I tried some things and they worked. That's why I posted like that

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <s>78</s> 77 bytes

```
String f(String a){while(!a.equals(a=a.replaceFirst(".\\^H","")));return a;}
```

Comment: You can remove the space after the comma to save one char.

Answer (score 2):

## (Visual)FoxPro any version 80 bytes

```
PARA t
DO WHILE AT('^H',t)>0
t = STRT(t,SUBS(t,AT('^H',t)-1,3))
ENDDO
RETU t
```

Repeating string translation to empty by finding ^H and backing up one character.

Answer (score 2):

## rs, 8 bytes

Technically, this doesn't count, as it depends on a feature I added after this question was posted. However, I think it's pretty neat.

```
+?1.\^H/
```

[Live demo and test cases](http://kirbyfan64.github.io/rs/index.html?script=%2B%3F1.%5C%5EH%2F&input=Horse%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EHCow%0ABe%20nice%20to%20this%20fool%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EHgentleman%2C%20he%27s%20visiting%20from%20corporate%20HQ.%0A123%5EH45%5EH%5EH%5EH78%5EH%0ADigital%20Trauma%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EHMaria%20Tidal%20Tug%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EHDigital%20Trauma).

Comment: Is the new feature a limit replacement?

Comment: @xnor Yes: the `?1`.

Comment: @Optimizer Why? You're losing to Gema anyway. :O

Comment: Yeah :( . Saw gema after posting comment

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
œṣ⁾^HṖ;¥/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5Ic7Fz9q3Bfn8XDnNOtDS/X/H25/1LQm8v//aC5OJY/8ouLUOA8YdM4vV9IBCjulKuRlJqcqlOQrlGRkFiuk5efnwNSkp@aV5KTmJubpKGSkqhcrlGUWZ5Zk5qUrpBXl5yok5xcV5BcllqQqeATqgc0yNDKO8zAxhWg2t4jzAIu6ZKZnliTmKIQUJZbmJiJcgAl9E4syExVCMlNAqkvT8SmN80A1FmyTo6NjnIcTSBLIjQUA)

Not a new approach, but the question was missing a Jelly answer

### How it works

```
œṣ⁾^HṖ;¥/ - Main link. Takes a string S on the left
  ⁾^H     - Yield "^H"
œṣ        - Split on "^H"
       ¥/ - Reduce by the following:
     Ṗ    -   Remove the last character
      ;   -   And append the right argument
```

Comment: ping me in an hour :P

Answer (score 2):

## Vim, <s>38</s> 35 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to Leo!

```
qa:%s/\([^H]\|\^\@<!.\)\^H//g
@aq@a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/vzDRSrVYP0YjOs4jNqYmJi7GwUZRL0YzJs5DXz@dyyGx0CHx/3@P/KLi1DgPGHTOLwcA)

See [Razetime's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223119/95792) for a shorter and smarter version of this.

````
qa:%s/\([^H]\|\^\@<!.\)\^H//g
@aq@a

qa                                     Start recording a macro a
  :%s/                                 Substitute in entire file
      \([^H]\|\^\@<!H\)                Regex for the character to be deleted
        [^H]                           A character that isn't H
            \|                         or
                    H                  an H
              \^\@<!                   that doesn't have a ^ before it
                       \^H             All of that followed by ^H
                          //           Replace with empty string
                            g          Global flag so it replaces multiple times
                                       Enter the command
@a                                     Recursively call macro a
  q                                    Stop recording
   @a                                  Run the macro
```
````

Comment: You need to pass V the `-v` flag in order to use verbose mode that turns <cr> into a carriage return [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/vzDRSrVYP0YjOs4jNqYmJi7GwUZRL0YzJs5DXz/dJrnIziGx0CHx/3@P/KLi1DgPGHTOL/@vWwYA "V (vim) – Try It Online") 
You could also directly insert a newline in the code instead [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/vzDRSrVYP0YjOs4jNqYmJi7GwUZRL0YzJs5DXz@dyyGx0CHx/3@P/KLi1DgPGHTOLwcA "V (vim) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Java - 123 bytes

I personally like the `g---1` part the best.

```java
String f(char[] a){String b="";for(int g=-1;++g<a.length;b=(a[g++]=='^'?b.substring(0,b.length()-1):b+a[g---1]));return b;}
```

expanded (slightly):

```java
  String f(char[] a) {
      String b = "";
      for (int g = -1;
           ++g < a.length;
           b = (a[g++]=='^' 
                ? b.substring(0, b.length() - 1) 
                : b + a[g---1])
      );
      return b;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 74 + 2 = 76 Bytes

I've tried a few approaches so far, this is the best I've been able to come up with so far.

```py
n=input();o='';c=0
for l in n:d=l=='^';o=[o+l*(1-c),o[:-1]][d];c=d
print o
```

Comment: Where are those 2 extra bytes coming from?

Comment: @xnor input has to be surrounded by quotes for this to work. I forgot to put that in the post.

Comment: I think the usual convention has been to allow string arguments to be taken in quotes for free, but I'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch - 138 bytes

```
@!! 2>nul||cmd/q/v/c%0 %1&&exit/b
set s=%1&for /F %%a in ('"prompt $H&echo on&for %%b in (1)do rem"')do set D=%%a
echo %s:^H=!D! !D!%
```

The first line is a way of saving a few bytes over the lengthy `@echo off&setLocal enableDelayedExpansion` (which turns echo off and enables the delayed expansion of variables, in case you were wondering). I explained it in [Tips for Golfing in Batch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20614/tips-for-golfing-in-batch).

The second line is a neat little trick to save the a backspace control character into a variable. It's pretty hacky, and I can't pretend to take credit for it. It's sort of explained [here](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1344). Basically uses the prompt command to generate a backspace character and captures it in a variable - in this case `!D!`.

The final line then performs the simple string manipulation of - replace `^H` with `!D!<SPACE>!D!`.

```
C:\>bsp.bat "testing^H^H^H test"
"test test"
```

<strike>Unfortunately it breaks with cases like `"AAA^HB^H^H"` - where it should produce `"A"`, it instead produces `"A"B`. Which is somewhat confusing. I'll have to look into how Batch string manipulation works in some more depth.</strike>

```
C:\>bsp.bat "AAA^HB^H^H"
"A"B
```

Thanks to to some helpful people [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395521/control-characters-and-string-manipulation/31397016#31397016) - I now realize that I was only saving the backspace character (0x08), and so was only overwriting the characters. It now works with examples like the following:

```
C:\>bsp.bat "AAA^HB^H^H"
"A"
```

Comment: there's a shorter version: `set s=%1&for /F %%a in ('prompt $H^&cmd /k^<nul')do set D=%%a`

Answer (score 1):

### Mumps, 84 Bytes

```
R Z S T="",Y=$L(Z,"^H") F I=1:1:Y{S T=T_$P(Z,"^H",I) S:I<Y T=$E(T,1,$L(T)-1)} W !,T
```

This could probably be made shorter as a function (1 byte I was able to save in quick testing) but I kinda like the one-liner aspect... :-)

The braces come from the Intersystems Cache flavour of Mumps which is what I'm most versed in.

Answer (score 1):

## jq 1.5, <s>41</s> 37 bytes

(34 characters code + 3 characters command line option.)

```
reduce(./"^H")[]as$t("";.[:-1]+$t)
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ bin/jq -R -r 'reduce(./"^H")[]as$t("";.[:-1]+$t)' <<< "Be nice to this fool^H^H^H^Hgentleman, he's visiting from corporate HQ."
Be nice to this gentleman, he's visiting from corporate HQ.
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=reduce%28./%22%5EH%22%29[]as$t%28%22%22%3B.[:-1]%2B$t%29&j=%22Be%20nice%20to%20this%20fool%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EHgentleman,%20he%27s%20visiting%20from%20corporate%20HQ.%22) (Passing `-R` through URL is not supported – so input passed as JSON string literal. Passing `-r` through URL is not supported – check Raw Output yourself.)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>39</s> <s>38</s> 36 bytes

There was no ><> answer so I thought I'd add one.

```
i:0(?v:'^'=?\
     ~   ~~i/
;!?lr<ro
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 60 bytes

```
b=n=>(v=n.search('^H'))>0?b(n.replace(n.slice(v-1,v+2),'')):n
```

Not as good as edc65's answer, but I wanted to try something that didn't use Regex.

Answer (score 1):

## bash, 50 bytes

```
while [ "$a" != "${a/?^H/}" ];do a=${a/?^H/};done
```

Sample:

```
a=$'Horse^H^H^H^H^HCow'
while [ "$a" != "${a/?^H/}" ];do a=${a/?^H/};done
echo $a
Cow

a="Be nice to this fool^H^H^H^Hgentleman, he's visiting from corporate HQ."
while [ "$a" != "${a/?^H/}" ];do a=${a/?^H/};done
echo $a
Be nice to this gentleman, he's visiting from corporate HQ.
```

This could work with real (binaries) backspaces as well:

```
a=$'Be nice to this fool\b\b\b\bgentleman, he'\'$'s visiting from corporate HQ.'
echo $a.. but:
Be nice to this gentleman, he's visiting from corporate HQ... but:
printf %q\\n "$a"
$'Be nice to this fool\b\b\b\bgentleman, he\'s visiting from corporate HQ.'

while [ "$a" != "${a/?$'\b'/}" ];do a=${a/?$'\b'/};done
printf %q\\n "$a"
Be\ nice\ to\ this\ gentleman\,\ he\'s\ visiting\ from\ corporate\ HQ.
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 60 Bytes

I know there is already a JS answer here, but wanted to do it without regexes, because regex is really almost a language by itself. I'm sorry if you feel I shouldn't post this, this is my first post.
`X` is the string to be operated upon.

```js
while((z=x.indexOf('^D'))>0){x=x.slice(0,z-1)+x.slice(z+2);}
```

#### Test

Put this into your browser's address bar.

```js
javascript:x=prompt('Enter the sentence to be erased');while((z=x.indexOf('^D'))>0){x=x.slice(0,z-1)+x.slice(z+2);}alert(x);
```

I love JS because it will let you do things like saying `(z=x.indexOf('^D))>0`, and it will both assign `z.indexOf('^D');` to `x` and evaluate `z.indexOf('^D')` in the condition, which saves me precious bytes in this problem. It's not very useful otherwise, but it's fun!

Comment: No problem posting another answer in a language that was already used. But please note that unless the task specifies otherwise, by default a program or a function is expected. Your is just a snippet. And please post your code in code block markup, so scripts like [Code Golf UserScript Enhancement Pack](http://stackapps.com/questions/2048/code-golf-userscript-enhancement-pack) can insert the code size beside the code.

Comment: [Here is the relevant meta consensus regarding snippets as answers.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) Note that [unnamed functions are fine.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/should-function-literals-be-allowed-when-a-function-is-asked-for/1503#1503)

Answer (score 1):

## Emacs Lisp, <s>45</s> 73 bytes

```
(lambda(s)(while(string-match".^H"s)(set's(replace-match"" nil nil s)))s)
```

Searches for the first occurence of anything else and `^H` as long as it exists and replaces it with an empty string.

<s>Old, incorrect version</s>

```
(lambda(s)(replace-regexp-in-string".^H"""s))
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm afraid this is not enough – you have to do the replacing in multiple steps so “one^Hff^H^H^Huch” gets transformed into “ouch”.

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 172 bytes

```
WITH v(s,i)AS(SELECT:1,INSTR(:1,'^')FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT LPAD(s,i-2)||SUBSTR(s,i+2),INSTR(s,'^',1,2)-3 FROM v WHERE i>0AND'^'<>s)SELECT s FROM v WHERE INSTR(s,'^')=0;
```

Un-golfed

```
WITH v(s,i) AS                        -- Recursive view, s-> string, i->pos of first ^
(
  SELECT :1,INSTR(:1,'^')             -- Initialisation view 
  FROM   DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT LPAD(s,i-2)||SUBSTR(s,i+2),  -- Remove the ^ at pos i and the characters before and after 
         INSTR(s,'^',1,2)-3           -- Compute the pos of the next ^ (the 2nd of s as before the remove just above)
  FROM   v 
  WHERE  i>0                          -- Exit clause : no more ^
    AND  s<>'^'                       -- Needed to circumvent oracle's cycle detection, without it 123^H45^H^H^H78^H will fail
)
SELECT s FROM v WHERE INSTR(s,'^')=0; -- Keep only the row without any ^
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>23</s> 16 bytes

-7 bytes by rereading question (specifically, "`^` will only appear as `^H`")

```
{x_/3#-1+x?"^"}/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY2xCsIwFEV/5RGHKlpLraLoIKhDFgehcyTUJH3YJpKkWhC/vVakiAhyt8u5555DrXTTyOW9PkZJL4yH9Zow8ogaGfQJNdYJRrtszY2syEaAxkyAN@BzdCCNKTpCCe0LUXI9glwEDq7o0KNWIK0pITP2Yiz3Auhh3JriScLodPaezheMtt0OFXpeQGp5VfLP92/23CKHFE8vulL/UEa/tWTQPAE)

Removes one instance of `?^H` on each invocation, and is run until convergence (i.e. no more `^`'s are present).

- `{...}/` run function on (implicit) input until it converges
- `-1+x?"^"` get the index of the character immediately prior to the first `^` in `x`
- `x_/3#` drop the value occurring at that index three times

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 9 bytes

```
‛^H/ƒλ$Ṫp
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCLigJteSC/Gks67JOG5qnAiLCIiLCJIb3JzZV5IXkheSF5IXkhDb3ciXQ==) Port of [caird coinheringaahing's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223113/100664).

```
   /      # Split on
‛^H       # "^H"
    ƒλ--- # Reduce by
        p # Prepend to the first item
      $Ṫ  # The second with its last item removed
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript ES6, <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```js
f=s=>s==(s=s.replace(/.\^H/,""))?s:f(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

## , 8 chars / 10 bytes (noncompetitive)

```
ïė/.\^H/
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin//interpreter.html?eval=false&input=Be%20nice%20to%20this%20fool%5EH%5EH%5EH%5EHgentleman%2C%20he%27s%20visiting%20from%20corporate%20HQ.&code=%C3%AF%C4%97%2F.%5C%5EH%2F)</kbd>

Works like all of the other JSGL's.

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
'.\^H'⎕R''⍠'ML'1⍣≡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVFNSxxBEL3Pr6jgoRV0vzJLzEKQ1RxmwUWic5SFdqZntnG6e@iuSSIhJyEkCyO5BHIJaLx69Rf4T/qPbGrc2UgISEHX49WrD17zsthJL3hh8uWSdU5nEfNXP44Z8/U1mx6yvq9v/bebpa9/wZRLDVmlE5RGw6arzpR0jvBWEDT1cfpwo5gDFKosOArIjIV4cgSbyqQykyIFNMBTXuLW6LFjjli6UbebzDl2HPLkXHwkrHPRSYzqouXaJVaW2B0Owt5wT70Jw/B12At3N9YgCDL/5buvrwZ@cUmnnxwf0BtHk5PVUbFwKOzfs4NgTPJegEQT@ERaSmyiywpHwLZ9fe8Xt2P/9SfRfYKtgvjPZMXYL377@i5o244qbPuyRvC0ERLuhHvcwiJjnZhF6zgwH9iqsC9Ay0Q0puBcOrLLFGtVLjQWQnG9DXPByNT30kmUOofMGgWJsaWxjcfRu047rj94OYvC4ar/1S795Ip/K3OJvIDY8krxp0P@jym3kkMs00Zd5c9JZ9G/Y9tdxIuiMED5kFt78YIt/wA)

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 81 bytes

```swift
let f={(s:inout _)in while(s+"").contains("^"){s={s.replacing}()(#/.\^H/#,"",1)}}
```

Call it like this:

```swift
var s = "Horse^H^H^H^H^HCow"
f(&s)
print(s) // "Cow"
```