# Inverse Ax+B/Cx+D sized function

Tags: code-golf, string, math

Let's assume that

$$
f(x) = \frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}
$$

Where, \$x\$ is a variable and \$A\$,\$B\$,\$C\$,\$D\$ are constants.

Now we have to find out the inverse function of \$f(x)\$, mathematically \$f^{-1}(x)\$, To do this first we assume,

$$
y = f(x)
\\\rightarrow y=\frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}
\\\rightarrow Cxy+Dy=Ax+B
\\\rightarrow Cxy-Ax=-Dy+B
\\\rightarrow x(Cy-A)=-Dy+B
\\\rightarrow x=\frac{-Dy+B}{Cy-A}
$$

Then, we know that

$$
y=f(x)
\\\rightarrow f^{-1}(y)=x
\\\rightarrow f^{-1}(y)=\frac{-Dy+B}{Cy-A} ..... (i)
$$

And from \$(i)\$ equation, we can write \$x\$ instead of \$y\$

$$
\\\rightarrow f^{-1}(x)=\frac{-Dx+B}{Cx-A}
$$

So, \$\frac{-Dx+B}{Cx-A}\$ is the inverse function of \$f(x)\$

This is a very long official mathematical solution, but we have a "cool" shortcut to do this:

1. Swap the position of the first and last constant diagonally, in this example \$A\$ and \$D\$ will be swapped, so it becomes:

$$
\frac{Dx+B}{Cx+A}
$$

2. Reverse the sign of the replaced constants, in this example \$A\$ is positive (\$+A\$) so it will be negative \$-A\$, \$D\$ is positive (\$+D\$) so it will be negative \$-D\$

$$
\frac{-Dx+B}{Cx-A}
$$

And VOILA!! We got the inverse function \$\frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}\$ in just two steps!!

---

## Challenge

**(Input of \$\frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}\$ is given like `Ax+B/Cx+D`)**

Now, let's go back to the challenge.

Input of a string representation of a function of \$\frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}\$ size, and output its inverse function in string representation.

I have just shown two ways to that (Second one will be easier for programs), there may be other ways to do this, good luck!

## Test cases

**(Input of \$\frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}\$ is given like `Ax+B/Cx+D`)**

```
4x+6/8x+7 -> -7x+6/8x-4
2x+3/2x-1 -> x+3/2x-2
-4x+6/8x+7 -> -7x+6/8x+4
2x+3/2x+1 -> x+3/2x+2
```

**Or you can give it using list of A,B,C,D**

```
4,6,8,7 -> -7x+6/8x-4
```

Or you can output `-7,6,8,-4`

## Rules

- **Input is always in \$\frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}\$ size, and is guaranteed to be valid.**
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- Trailing/Leading whitespace in output is allowed.
- If possible, please link to an online interpreter (e.g. [TIO](https://tio.run)) to run your program on.
- Please explain your answer. This is not necessary, but it makes it easier for others to understand.
- Languages newer than the question are allowed. This means you could create your own language where the empty program calculates this number, but don't expect any upvotes.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

(Some terminology might be incorrect, feel free ask me if you have problems)

Comment: The expression string I/O in this challenge seems like a bad idea for [many of the usual reasons](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19357/20260). It's further confusing here that `ax+b/cx+d` represents `(ax+b)/(cx+d)`. I'd suggest loosening it, though it seems that not much remains in mapping `(A,B,C,D) -> (-D,B,C,-A)`.

Comment: @xnor I have loosened output format, you can give input in either of the two formats

Comment: the expression is `(ax+b)/(cx+d)`

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 27 bytes

```perl
sub{@_[0,3]=map-$_,@_[3,0]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r5Jm@7@4NKnaIT7aQMc41jY3sUBXJV4HyDXWMYit/W@tkqZrp@HgpmmtEm@blZ@Zp6SjpOPg9t9Ex0zHQsecy0jHWMdIR9eQSxdVxPBffkFJZn5e8X/dnAI3HQA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 48 bytes

```
^-
+
^\d
-$&
(.\d+)(.*)([-+].+)
$3$2$1
^-

^\+
-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcoxDkAwGAbQ/TtHSevL36YluIFDqIaEwWIQQ29fduvLu4/nvLZS6WktSUCkuENUDW3jTqNtY/QsXCwNVKuC8vjatwgppcvs3Zg5IGS2LmTxkB/Svw) Link includes test cases. Assumes that `1x` is always written as such. Explanation:

```
^-
+
^\d
-$&
```

Negate and enforce the sign on `A`.

```
(.\d+)(.*)([-+].+)
$3$2$1
```

Swap `A` and `D`.

```
^-

^\+
-
```

Negate `D`, removing the sign if it was negative.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
÷↭⫙'N^N^W
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C3%B7%E2%86%AD%E2%AB%99%27N%5EN%5EW&inputs=%5B2%2C%203%2C%202%2C%20-1%5D&header=&footer=)

### Explained

```
÷↭⫙'N^N^W
÷          # Push every item of the input onto the stack
 ↭        # And rotate the top three items: [a, b, c, d] → [a, d, b, c]
   ⫙'      # Rotate the entire stack left
     N^N^W # Negate the top and bottom of the stack and wrap into a list
```

Comment: Makes me think of the [^H jokes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52946/backhandedhhhhhhspaces)

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```
,[-<->],>,>,[->-<]>.<<<.>.<<.
```

Commented:

```
,            #input A into cell 0
[-<->]       #decrement cells 0 and -1 until cell 0 contains 0 and cell -1 contains -A
,>,>,        #input B,C,D into cells 0,1,2
[->-<]       #decrement cells 2 and 3 until cell 2 contains 0 and cell 3 contains -D
>.<<<.>.<<.  #output -D,B,C and -A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ1rXRtcuVscOCKN17XRtYu30bGxs9ECk3v//jk7OLgA)

Very rarely, a challenge comes along where Brainfuck is somewhat competitive.

Takes 4 bytes as input, gives 4 bytes as output.

The normal form of interface for Brainfuck is an ASCII terminal, so the input `ABCD` in the TIO link is intrepreted as `[65,66,67,68]`. Outputs are per the table below. Note that signed negative numbers are treated as their unsigned 8 bit counterparts, and give extended ASCII output in the range 128-255, in accordance with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII#/media/File:Table_ascii_extended.png

```
Input             Signed Output    Unsigned equivalent ASCII output  
A=65              -65              191                  ¿
B=66               66               66                  B
C=67               67               67                  C
D=68              -68              188                  ¼
```

After swapping A and D, we arrive at the required output `[-68,66,67,-65]`, which in ASCII looks like  `¼BC¿`

Answer (score 4):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <s>7</s> 6 bytes [<sup>(SBCS)</sup>](https://github.com/Lyxal/Keg/blob/master/Codepage.txt)

Input as a list. Outputs by values on the stack.

Footer outputs entire stack joined by newlines.

```
÷±'±$"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////8PZDG9UPbVRR@h/3qGOinqGlts7/aBMdMx0LHfNYAA)

### Explanation

```
        # Input as a list    (e.g. [4, 6, 8, 7])
÷       # Dump it onto stack (Stack = [ 4, 6, 8, 7])
 ±      # Negate TOS         (Stack = [ 4, 6, 8,-7])
  '     # Shift left         (Stack = [ 6, 8,-7, 4])
   ±    # Negate TOS         (Stack = [ 6, 8,-7,-4])
    $   # Exchange TOS       (Stack = [ 6, 8,-4,-7])
     "  # Shift right        (Stack = [-7, 6, 8,-4])
```

#### Footer explanation

```
^        # Reverse the stack (So that the first item of TOS is outputted first)
 ∑       # Apply to entire stack:
  .      # Output TOS as integer
   19+,  # Print a trailing newline
```

### Credits

- Saved 1 byte thanks to @Lyxal

Comment: [This works for 6 bytes. How you have managed to beat 05AB1E and APL amazes me. Well done!](https://tio.run/##y05N////8PZDG9UPbVRR@h/3qGOinqGlts7/aBMdMx0LHfNYAA "Keg – Try It Online")

Comment: @Lyxal Nice, I forgot that implicit input evaluated by default.

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 43 bytes

Takes input as and outputs as an array.

```powershell
$n=$args;-1,1,2,-4|%{$n[$_]*(2*($_-gt0)-1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyXPViWxKL3YWtdQx1DHSEfXpEa1WiUvWiU@VkvDSEtDJV43vcRAU9dQs/b///@G/43@G/83AQA)

#### Less Fun [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 31 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b,$c,$d)-$d,$b,$c,-$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRRyVJRyVZRyVFU1clBcrRVUn8//@/4X@j/8b/TQA)

#### Most Unfun [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 30 bytes

```powershell
-$args[3],$args[1,2],-$args[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X1clsSi9ONo4VgfCMNQxitWBChrE/v//3/C/0X/j/yYA)

#### Least Useful [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 26 bytes

```powershell
"-{3},{1},{2},-{0}"-f$args
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0m32rhWp9oQiI1qdXSrDWqVdNNUEovSi////2/43@i/8X8TAA)

Comment: unfun `$args[1,2]`. useful is useful! :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Dash](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell), 23 bytes

```sh
$((-$4)) $2 $3 $((-$1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcixCsIwEIDhPU/xDzc0ww1Jiwq@ikuaO0ihGLCCjx@Lm@P3WTna@LRtd15ejMJKxe5Y5/A3qkhBVqQiZ3ttnceQaVJZYkQyMvNjinFYf/pYuHDjGjIzGU1B/yeFLw)

### Usage

Requires positional parameters for each of A, B, C, and D. Before evaluating the command. Also the code evaluates to just four strings, so run `echo` command with those code (may not portable when D is originally positive, as hyphen-parameter may be treated as an option).

### How it works

- dollar-double-parentheses is arithmetic expansion.

---

## Polyglot for Bash, OSH, bosh, Dash, ksh, yash, and Zsh, 25 bytes

```sh
$((- $4)) $2 $3 $((- $1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VckxCoQwFADRPqeY4hemSJEouuBVtonJh4hiYBX2@FHYast5s52lfcu6Kx@NmchCIs/kyqkXziERWZCEPKypVN5Nuu4Zg7VIQHp@7a1tuR7aBkZeTCbQE3DeuH/x5gY)

### Differences

- A space between hyphen and dollar. This is a workaround for negative values; if one of them was expanded to `$((--1))`, for example, Dash, OSH and Bash parse as minus of minus one, but other four don't; they parse to decrement a variable named one, although one is a constant.

---

## Polyglots for Bash and OSH, 19 bytes

Thanks, 2x-1!

```bash
$[-$4] $2 $3 $[-$1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vci9CoMwFIDRPU/xDXe9Q6JowUepDvm5EEEa0EIfP7Zjx3NSvGr/1P0wTouFSCJTFkrjsjeqSEQSkpFvW66NtctTZdyQgAz84Lde2sv6yMSD2QUGAuqd/o93Nw)

### What the heck

`$[ ... ]` is historically equivalent to `$(( ... ))`, which is [not adopted for POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_06_04).

OBTW adding a space betwee hyphen and dollar (which is +2 bytes), the code would be polyglot for Zsh, too.

Comment: [Port in Bash is 19 bytes](https://tio.run/##Vci9CoMwFIDRPU/xDXe9Q6JowUepDvm5EEEa0EIfP7Zjx3NSvGr/1P0wTouFSCJTFkrjsjeqSEQSkpFvW66NtctTZdyQgAz84Lde2sv6yMSD2QUGAuqd/o93Nw "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: I thought my code would work on every other POSIX-compliant shells, but it worked on Bash and Dash only; failed on OSH, bosh, ksh, yash, Zsh. This is because `$((--1))`, for example, is parsed as if `1` were a variable although not. I found another point to write portable shell scripts.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), <sup><s>9</s></sup> 7 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
-∘⌽@1 4
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=033UMeNRz14HQwUTAA&f=S1MwUTBTsFAwBwA&i=AwA&r=tryAPL&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

A function submission which accepts an array.

-2 bytes from rak1507.

Comment: Don't need parens

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
À`(s()Á
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cEOCRrGG5uHG//@jTXTMdCx0zGMB)

```python
         # implicit input                [A, B, C, D]
À        # rotate the input left         [B, C, D, A]
 `       # dump all values on the stack  B, C, D, A
  (      # negate top of stack           B, C, D, -A
   s     # swap top two values           B, C, -A, D
    (    # negate top of stack           B, C, -A, -D
     )   # collect all values in a list  [B, C, -A, -D]
      Á  # rotate the list right         [-D, B, C, -A]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 26 bytes

```ruby
->n{a,b,c,d=n
[-d,b,c,-a]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOlEnSSdZJ8U2jytaNwXM1k2Mrf1foJAWHW2oY6RjrGMSG8sF5promOlY6JjHxv4HAA)

Shorter than my brainfuck answer by a few bytes, but not as interesting.

Answer (score 3):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 22 bytes

```
[-.[3],.[1:3][],-.[0]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z9aVy/aOFZHL9rQyjg2OlYHyDWIjQWKm@iY6VjomMdyRRvpGOsY6RjGAgA)

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 31 bytes

```
(a,b,c,d)->new int[]{-d,b,c,-a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/BCsIwDIbvPkWOLXQ9iQqi4MWbJ4/iIWs76aydtNlkjD377Doxhz8hJN@f1NhhUevn9G5LZxUohzHCBa2HYQUprCcTKlQGzkOqb3eIjesMSzWgmLXMqrJqvh/z2g8XCSmlrrEaXgnKrhSsfyQKhkfkP485zlAdJoaiFEpoXhy9@UD2GwqdmwWO0/4/fu0jmZdsWpLvRCTnWZ1ekS1ZJ08hYB8lNYsbq@Ry81psxE5sOecLaFyN0xc)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 22 bytes

```javascript
(a,b,c,d)=>[-d,b,c,-a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f9fI1EnSSdZJ0XT1i5aNwXM1k2M/f8fAA)

Comment: don't think it can get shorter than this...

Comment: @ophact It's not a very interesting challenge.

Comment: I know, definitely not the best challenge

Comment: @ophact See xnor's comment above.

Answer (score 2):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 16 + 6 = 22 or 53 bytes

Version 1: 16 (but takes extra input)

```
{?>>>>*}
 >>>>>^
```

After the four numbers, also input -1 1 1 -1 (+6 bytes). I can't figure out how to do it shortly any other way. [Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoiez8+Pj4+Kn1cbiA+Pj4+Pl4iLCJ2IjoxLCJpIjoiMSAyIDMgNCAtMSAxIDEgLTEifQ==)

Version 2, 53 bytes

```
{?>*}v<0
 v ^<<^-1
 ?>>*}
v<  ^v<1
v 0>^v
v1-^<<
>>*}
```

It's complicated. Multiplies the first and last numbers by -1. I'm a noob at convey and wait was crashing the program. [Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoiez8+Kn12PDBcbiB2IF48PF4tMVxuID8+Pip9XG52PCAgXnY8MVxudiAwPl52XG52MS1ePDxcbj4+Kn0iLCJ2IjoxLCJpIjoiMSAyIDMgNCJ9)

Answer (score 2):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 19 bytes

```
0?0r-sbscsd-lcldlbf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/A3qBItzipOLk4RTcnOSclJynt/38TBTMFCwVzAA)

### Explanation

```
                     # Say the input is 4 6 8 7.
                     # Effect:
0                    # [0]
 ?                   # [0, 4, 6, 8, 7]
  0r-                # [0, 4, 6, 8,-7]
     sbscsd          # [0, 4] (B=-7, C=8, D=4)
           -         # [-4]   (B=-7, C=8, D=4)
            lcldlb   # [-4, 8, 4, -7]
                  f  # Output in reverse (i.e. -7 6 8 -4)
```

Answer (score 0):

## MMIX, 44 bytes (11 instrs)

Inverts `mobius *a` into `mobius *b`.
This is with `typedef double mobius[4];`.

Note that NaNs and zeroes have the sign negated; to not do so would cost an extra instruction (zeroing out `$2` at start and replacing `INCL $255,#8000` with `FSUB $255,$2,$255`).

(jxd)

```
00000000: 8fff0018 e4ff8000 afff0100 8fff0010  Ɓ”¡ðỵ”⁰¡Ḥ”¢¡Ɓ”¡Ñ
00000010: afff0108 8fff0008 afff0110 8fff0000  Ḥ”¢®Ɓ”¡®Ḥ”¢ÑƁ”¡¡
00000020: e4ff8000 afff0118 f8000000           ỵ”⁰¡Ḥ”¢ðẏ¡¡¡
```

Disassembled:

```
invmob  LDOU $255,$0,24
        INCH $255,#8000
        STOU $255,$1
        LDOU $255,$0,16
        STOU $255,$1,8
        LDOU $255,$0,8
        STOU $255,$1,16
        LDOU $255,$0
        INCH $255,#8000
        STOU $255,$1,24
        POP  0,0
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 26 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c,d:[-d,b,c,-a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUSFRJ0knWSfFKlo3BczSTYz9/x8A)

4 input. Output is list.