# How to convert HEX2 to RGBA?

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion, conversion, hexadecimal, color

The world of art is full of colour, but the world of the network is even fuller than the world of art of diferent colours and it's renderings. That's why we need to know how to convert one type of colour format to another.

#### The challenge is self-evident:

Write a program / function than converts an given [HEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Hex_triplet) code (`#00ff0080`, for instance) to [RGBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) (like `rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)`).

## Rules:

- External libraries/ built-ins for converting HEX to RGBA are disallowed. However, jQuery and syntax replacers like that are acceptable.
- Standard Input/Output rules apply.
- Format of the alpha can be between (1 == 100%) or the other (100 == 100%) that's not really important.
- The output *is flexible*, as long as it returns the 4 converted values (as a String, Array, List, your choice).
- You may choose to take the input without the `#` in the beginning. Hence, you can take input as either `#RRGGBBAA` or `RRGGBBAA`. You can assume that the hex code (excluding the `#`) will always be 8 characters long.
- You should divide all the values by 255, including the alpha. The minimum decimal precision (for the alpha will be 2 decimal places).

## Test Cases

```
Input:  00ff0080
Output: 0, 255, 0, 0.5
```

## Scoring

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the code with the least amount of bytes wins.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61386/discussion-on-question-by-obsdarek-how-to-convert-hex2-to-rgba).

Comment: Are we required to take the "hex code" as a *string*? You say that we can take it without the leading `#`, in which case it would just be a 32-bit integer value. Is it legal to take it as that?

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>73</s> <s>54</s> 50 bytes

(Saved some bytes thanks to @LeakyNun, the edited challenge, and @CraigAyre.)

```
s=>s.match(/../g).map((c,i)=>('0x'+c)/(i-3?1:255))
```

```js
let f=

s=>s.match(/../g).map((c,i)=>('0x'+c)/(i-3?1:255))

console.log(f('00ff0080'));
```

Comment: Rick, it looks like we have the final spec for this now so you can update your answer.

Comment: As well as @Shaggy's comment you can save a few bytes by using `eval` instead of `parseInt`: `s=>s.match(/../g).map((x,i)=>eval('0x'+x)/(i-3?1:255))`

Comment: @CraigAyre, `eval` is a great alternative to `parseInt` for golfing purposes, thanks!

Comment: @RickHitchcock, no worries! You can also shave a couple of bytes from the regex using `/../g`. You might be able to reduce it even further using `replace` over `match`/`map`

Comment: Oh, I see the rules have changed, so the initial pound sign is no longer required.

Comment: Yeah, it's now optional. +2 bytes for supporting it isn't bad however!

Comment: Can't find a good `replace` solution that's shorter.  If you have one, you should post it – would be an interesting alternative.

Comment: @CraigAyre, found a great alternative to `parseInt` *and* `eval` for hexadecimal:  `+('0x'+c)`

Comment: @RickHitchcock, nice! You could even drop the conversion to number and divide the string directly to save another byte

Comment: Duh, of course!  : )

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, <s>13</s> 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as a string, without the leading `#`. Outputs the rgba value as an array.

```
ò mnG o÷#ÿ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=8iBtbkcgb/cj/w&input=IjAwZmYwMDgwIg)

```
ò mnG o÷#ÿ     :Implicit input of string
ò              :Partitions of length 2
  m            :Map
   n           :  Convert to integer from base
    G          :  16
      o        :Modify last element
       ÷       :  Divide by
        #ÿ     :  255
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
2ôH`255/)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f6PAWj4Sj@6r0Nf//NzBwczMwsDAAAA)

At least we have supporters like [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47066/emigna) to often use some common sense...(that's what you get for golfing all day and then you start producing stuff like `2ô16öRć255/¸ìR` ಠ_ಠ)

Comment: 5 bytes shorter: `2ôH\`žz/)`

Comment: @Emigna The challenge has been closed nevertheless...

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 63 bytes

Output as array

```php
$h=array_map(hexdec,str_split($argn,2));$h[3]/=255;print_r($h);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoMClkliUnmerZGCQlmZgYGGgZP1fJcM2sagosTI@N7FAIyO1IiU1Wae4pCi@uCAns0QDrF7HSFPTWiUj2jhW39bI1NS6oCgzryS@SEMlQ9P6/38A)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 80 bytes

Output as rgba value, Input without `#`

```php
$h=array_map(hexdec,str_split($argn,2));$h[3]/=255;echo"rgba(",join(",",$h),")";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoMClkliUnmerZGCQlmZgYGGgZP1fJcM2sagosTI@N7FAIyO1IiU1Wae4pCi@uCAns0QDrF7HSFPTWiUj2jhW39bI1NQ6NTkjX6koPSlRQ0knKz8zD0gp6ahkaOooaQIN/A8A)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 88 bytes

Output as rgba value, Input with `#`

```php
for(;$i<7;)$h[]=hexdec($argn[++$i].$argn[++$i]);$h[3]/=255;echo"rgba(",join(",",$h),")";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoMClkliUnmerpGxgkJZmYGBhoGT9Py2/SMNaJdPG3FpTJSM61jYjtSIlNVkDrDJaW1slM1YPia1pDVRkHKtva2Rqap2anJGvVJSelKihpJOVn5kHpJR0VDI0dZQ0gQb/BwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 139 bytes

```c
C(x){x=x>57?x-87:x-48;}
#define Z C(h[i])*16+C(h[++i]))
i;f(char*h){printf("rgba(");for(i=0;i<6;i++)printf("%i, ",Z;printf("%g)",(Z/256.);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxNDoIwFIT3PUVTY9JHqVYjP7GCC2@BcYHYwluIhrhoQjh7LQt0VvPNTKaRbdN4f@EORle4MsnOTubZ0clDrieyehiLvaEVvfDuijeIdqmYrRABgKC2vOnqIepgfA/YfyxnQ3uvOQNtXwPHQmk8pRqFgKVfY0xZXOkft8BiXm33SboBPfmQ0meNPYeR0KBlZ41SxuSKypLO9/8kEJn8Fw)

My other attempt clocked in at [145 bytes](https://tio.run/##TUy7CsIwFN3zFZeIkNs2GsU@MLQO/YKuikONSZvBIsUhUPrtMQgtnjOdp@KdUt7XzOHkSlel@cXxIj87firkTDZPbeygoYGa9Tcbx3eMDlm8ClwbV3iPdvgYRrc2AZo0xErDVN@OUY@TLYVc8rF7tIyivP64rjqkCWv2xzTboZx9cOHV2oHhRCBg6RkthNaFAF5BOPlzgiKz/wI). I'm not much of a C golfer, so this could probably be shorter.

Answer (score 3):

## Vim, 46 bytes

```
:s/../$((16#&)) /g␊iecho ␛$hhi*100/255␛:w !sh␊
```

Takes input without the `#` and returns by printing on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
Øhi$€’s2ḅ⁴÷4¦⁹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9qZWxsef//w5hoaSTigqzigJlzMuG4heKBtMO3NMKm4oG5////IjAwZmYwMDgwIg)

**How it Works**

```
Øhi$€’s2ḅ⁴÷4¦⁹ - main link, takes input without # and all lowercase
   $€             - to each input character:
  i               - return its 1-based index in
Øh                - the string "0123456789abcdef"
     ’            - decrement (otherwise 0 is mapped to 1 and f to 16)
      s2          - split the characters into groups of two
        ḅ⁴        - convert from base 16 to decimal
           4¦     - on the fourth element:
          ÷       - divide by
             ⁹    - 256
```

*-1 byte thanks to @EricTheOutgolfer*

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 72 bytes

Jörg´s array output version is unbeatable; but there are other options:

```php
<?=($a=hexdec($argn))>>24,",",255&$a>>16,",",255&$a>>8,",",(255&$a)>256;
```

Run as pipe with `-F`. `#` does not matter, plain csv output

or **73 bytes** (run with `-R`):

```php
for($a=hexdec($argn);$i++<4;)echo(255&$a>>32-8*$i)/($i<4?:256),","[$i>3];
```

**74 bytes** with the spaces:

```php
<?=($a=hexdec($argn))>>24,$c=", ",255&$a>>16,$c,255&$a>>8,$c,(255&$a)>256;
```

not so plain, **81 bytes**:

```php
rgba(<?=($a=hexdec($argn))>>24,$c=", ",255&$a>>16,$c,255&$a>>8,$c,(255&$a)/256?>)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), <s>47</s> <s>45</s> 41 bytes

```
[2#<$unhexmap(1::256)/', '#`'rgba(@id)'!]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcbRCoIwFIDh@z3FCYOzQdFxqcWI8D1EaG1nLcSSVKinX1L/xc83TtZ17FNqdHZaz4/I794OMjdGl5Xa4QYwu@DrdrWyvnuFqzbVJgghkSgEoiMhYPhFfzJ779xCyvW@KKsDKtHAaD@AsD0vG@YJArCLT2iBrYvpCw)

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 99 bytes

```
=HEX2DEC(LEFT(A1,2))&","&HEX2DEC(MID(A1,3,2))&","&HEX2DEC(MID(A1,5,2))&","&HEX2DEC(RIGHT(A1,2))/256
```

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, 50 bytes

```
INPUT H$RGBREAD VAL("&H"+H$)OUT R,G,B,A?R,G,B,A/#L
```

The hexadecimal string is converted to a number using VAL(), then RGBREAD extracts each byte. #L is a constant with the value 256.

RGBREAD is designed to extract the channels from an ARGB color, but really it just splits a 4 byte integer into 4 separate bytes, so the order doesn't matter.

Comment: I always like seeing [tag:basic] responses, but I am afraid that this response may be invalid, as it uses a built in for converting hexadecimal to rgba

Comment: I think it doesn't count as a hex->rgba builtin because it requires an extra step to convert the hex string into an integer.

Comment: Actually, looking at it again, I think you are right, the explicit conversion from hex to int would make it valid.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>73</s> 62 bytes

```powershell
$args-split'(..)'-ne''|%{"0x$_"/(1,1,1,256)[$i++]}|% *g "0.##"
```

-11 bytes thanks to Mazzy

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SpmCrUP1fJbEovVi3uCAns0RdQ09PU103L1VdvUa1WsmgQiVeSV/DUAcEjUzNNKNVMrW1Y2trVBW00hWUDPSUlZX@13KpAQ1SMjBISzMwsDBQ4lJSgoikGaQZphmlGSj9BwA)

Comment: `toString` is smart. [regexp instead substring](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SpmCrUP1fJbEovVi3uCAns0RdQ09PU103L1VdvUa1WsmgQiVeSV/DUAcEjUzNNKNVMrW1Y2trVBW00hWUDPSUlZX@13KpAQ1SMjBISzMwsDBQ4lJSgoikGaQZphmlGSj9BwA "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")?

Answer (score 1):

### JS ES2015, 84 bytes

```js
$=>{a=[1,3,5,7].map(b=>eval("0x"+$.substr(b,2)));a[3]=(a[3]/256);return a.join(",")}
```

this is a function. Run it using

```html
( CODE )("#00ff0080")
```

Answer (score 1):

## q/kdb+, 43 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{(16 sv'(.Q.n,6#.Q.a)?/:2 cut x)%1 1 1 256}
```

**Example:**

```
q){(16 sv'(.Q.n,6#.Q.a)?/:2 cut x)%1 1 1 256}"00ff0080"
0 255 0 0.5
```

**Explanation:**

```
{                                         } / anonymous lambda function
                        2 cut x             / split input into 2-char length lists
                     ?/:                    / returns index where (each-right) item is found in 'the list'
        (           )                       / 'the list'
              6#.Q.a                        / Q.a is lowercase alphabet, 6# takes first 6 chars
         .Q.n,                              / Q.n is "012..89", so prepend this onto the "abcdef"                         
  16 sv'                                    / converts each index from base 16 to base 10
 (                            )%1 1 1 256   / divide this output by 1,1,1,256 to get alpha in 0..1 range
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 24 bytes

Requires `⎕IO←0` which is default on many systems. Prompts for input as uppercase without `#`.

```apl
256÷⍨@3⊢16⊥⍉4 2⍴⍞⍳⍨⎕D,⎕A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862ovSkxL/G5maHd7@qHeFg/GjrkWGZo@6lj7q7TRRMHrUu@VR77xHvZuBckBdLjpAwvE/UNd/BTAAaeYyMHBzMzCwMAAA)

`⎕D,⎕A` **D**igits followed by **A**lphabet

`⍞⍳⍨` prompt for text input (mnemonic: console with quote) and find the **ɩ**ndex of each letter in that

`4 2⍴` **r**eshape as four row two column matrix

`⍉` transpose (because base conversion works columnwise)

`16⊥` evaluate as **base** sixteen

`⊢` yield (serves to separate 3 and 16)

`256÷⍨@3` divide the 4<sup>th</sup> element by 256

Answer (score 1):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 96 bytes

Yet another [basic](/questions/tagged/basic) answer; Takes input as string and outputs to the console.

```vb
Input""a$
For i=1To 7Step 2
?Dec(Mid$(a$,i,2))/(j+1);
If i=5Then j=255Fi
If i<7Then?", ";Fi
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3zOvoLRESSlRhcstv0gh09YwJF/BPLgktUDBiMveJTVZwzczRUUjUUUnU8dIU1NfI0vbUNOayzMNqNQ0JCM1TyHL1sjU1C0TLGRjDhKyV9JRULIGCvmlVpT8/29gkJZmYGBhAAA)

Comment: You can save a byte by removing the line break before `?`.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 90 bytes

An anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from the range `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window.

```vb
For i=1To 7Step 2:[B1]=i:?[Hex2Dec(Mid(A1,B1,2))]/IIf(i=7,256,1)&""+IIf(i<7,", ","");:Next
```

Answer (score 1):

## Batch, 150 bytes

```
@for /f "tokens=2-5 delims=. " %%a in ('ping/n 1 0x%1^|find "h"')do @echo/%%a,%%b,%%c&set/ay=%%d*100/255@set y=0.%y%@if %y%==0.100 set y=1@echo/%y%
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Batch](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20614/tips-for-golfing-in-batch) page for ways you can golf your program

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 42 bytes

```
{m:g/../.map({:16(~$_)}) »/«(1,1,1,255)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OtcqXV9PT18vN7FAo9rK0EyjTiVes1ZT4dBu/UOrNQx1QNDI1FSz9r@1QnFipUKahrqBQVqagYGFgbqm9X8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 62 bytes

```python
lambda h:[int(h[x:x+2],16)for x in(0,2,4)]+[int(h[6:],16)/255]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHDKjozr0QjI7rCqkLbKFbH0EwzLb9IoUIhM0/DQMdIx0QzVhuqwswKLK1vZGoa@7@gCCSYpqFuYJCWZmBgYaCuqfkfAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

```python
lambda h:[int(h[i-2:i],16)/2.**(8&i)for i in(2,4,6,8)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcrBDkAwDADQX@mJTYpqRBaJL8GBSLMmzLK4@Prxzi@@j78DZ5mWfG7Xfmzgx1nDY/ysNY@6YjfYlpuqMq5QK3cCBQ2GsccBnV1zTH8HMSWRCJGj0uYP)